# swapping vector element with a pointer from one derived class to another

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, vector, polymorphism

I have a chess game that originally used an stl list to store the chess pieces which I switched over to a vector for better performance. I understand that vectors do not support polymorphism so to get around this I'm storing a vector of `<Unit *>` instead of `<Unit>`. All of my chess piece objects (Pawn, Rook, Bishop, etc) inherit from the Unit class.

However there still seems to be an issue with the vector and heap corruption. I think I've tracked it down to the following function:

```
Unit *ChessGame::PromoteUnit(Unit *_oldUnit, UnitType _newType)
{

vector<Unit *> &army = (_oldUnit->m_gameColor == WHITE) ? m_whiteArmy : m_blackArmy;
Unit *newUnit = NULL;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < army.size(); ++i)
{
    if (army[i]->m_subId == _oldUnit->m_subId)
    {
        if (_newType == QUEEN && _oldUnit->m_gameColor == WHITE)
        {
            newUnit = new Queen(*_oldUnit);
            newUnit->ActiveTexture_(m_textureMan->TextureId_(WhiteQueen));
        }
        else if (_newType == KNIGHT && _oldUnit->m_gameColor == WHITE)
        {
            newUnit = new Knight(*_oldUnit);
            newUnit->ActiveTexture_(m_textureMan->TextureId_(WhiteKnight));
        }
        else if (_newType == QUEEN && _oldUnit->m_gameColor == BLACK)
        {
            newUnit = new Queen(*_oldUnit);
            newUnit->ActiveTexture_(m_textureMan->TextureId_(BlackQueen));
        }
        else if (_newType == KNIGHT && _oldUnit->m_gameColor == BLACK)
        {
            newUnit = new Knight(*_oldUnit);
            newUnit->ActiveTexture_(m_textureMan->TextureId_(BlackKnight));
        }

        newUnit->m_wasPawn = true;
        delete army[i];
        army[i] = newUnit;
        break;
    }
}

m_selectedUnit = newUnit;

return newUnit;
}
```

Since a pointer is only 4 bytes regardless of what it points to is there a reason why a stl vector would still have a problem in a case like this? My Pawn object is 8 bytes larger in size than the Knight or Queen being promoted to and would perhaps explain the weird memory errors I've been getting. When I back up on my turn history and hit my Demote function to reverse the promotion:

```
Unit *ChessGame::DemoteUnit(Unit *_oldUnit, UnitType _newType)
{
COUT("ChessGameManager::_DemoteUnit(Unit *, UnitType)");

vector<Unit *> &army = (_oldUnit->m_gameColor == WHITE) ? m_whiteArmy : m_blackArmy;
Unit *newUnit = NULL;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < army.size(); ++i)
{
    if (army[i]->m_subId == _oldUnit->m_subId)
    {
        newUnit = new Pawn();
        newUnit->m_wasPawn = false;

        if (_oldUnit->m_gameColor == WHITE)
            newUnit->ActiveTexture_(m_textureMan->TextureId_(WhitePawn));

        newUnit->m_gameColor = _oldUnit->m_gameColor;
        newUnit->MobilityValid_(false);
        newUnit->Color_(RvColor::ClrWhite);
        newUnit->m_square = _oldUnit->m_square;
        newUnit->m_captured = false;
        newUnit->m_origin = _oldUnit->m_origin;
        newUnit->m_subId = _oldUnit->m_subId;
        newUnit->m_visible = true;

        //newUnit->m_square->m_unit = newUnit;

        delete army[i];
        army[i] = newUnit;
        break;
    }
}

return newUnit;
}
```

It literally crashes on:

```
newUnit = new Pawn();
```

Stepping into new Pawn() causes it to crash inside the new operator when it attempts to use malloc to reserve the heap memory. Anyways I'm thinking it still has something to do with my lack of complete understanding of how the vector stl works. I know its nothing to do with my Pawn() constructor since its called plenty of times during the initialization of the game board.

Comment: Looks like a memory error. If you're on Linux or OS X, I would suggest using valgrind to root out any dynamic memory access issues: http://valgrind.org/

Comment: These are the only 2 methods that are running ?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the shortest complete program that demonstrates the error, and post that **complete**, **short** program in your question. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: Ok sorry about that, thanks for the link. I'll work on reducing the code then reproducing the error. That's good advice, I will probably wind up solving it after I do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect, but cannot prove from the information you have shared, that your copy constructor and copy assignment operator for `ChessGame` doing a shallow copy of `m_whiteArmy` and `m_blackArmy`. (Note: if you don't provide a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator, the compiler provides them for you. The compiler-provided ones do shallow copies.)

You have violated the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

You can fix this by:

- Never copying a `ChessGame` object.
- Enforcing the above by:

  - (pre-C++11): declaring and not defining a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator.
  - (C++11): specifying `= delete` after the copy constructor and copy assignment operator declarations.
- Changing your pointers to smart pointers (like `std::shared_ptr`)., or
- Implementing a deep copy in your copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: I actually never copy the ChessGame class at all in my code so I dont think that is the problem and I only ever pass it to methods or functions by pointer or reference.

Comment: I guess I was mostly asking if the code above looks legit in terms of how I'm trying to use a vector and based on the feedback I'm guessing what I posted looks ok which means I need to try and look elsewhere. My biggest problem at the moment now is trying to figure out how to even go about debugging an error that breaks in "new" :( If somewhere my memory is going out of bounds and causing existing contiguous allocations to get stepped on it will be hard to know where to set break points. If I had an threads it would be one thing but I don't.

Comment: I'm going to reduce the code like Rob said then repost my findings later. Thanks guys, appreciate all the help!

Comment: Good luck, @RyanVanDyke - the two techniques I can suggest to debug memory corruption are: 1) valgrind on Linux (or some similar product for Windows), and 2) testcase reduction (also called machete debugging.) If you get a short, complete program that fails, and you don't understand why, feel free to open a new question.

Comment: It occurs to me also, that you might try to audit your use of `new` and `delete`. See if you can prove these assertions: for every `new` there is *exactly one* `delete`; for every `new[]`, there is *exactly one* `delete[]`. If you code path is too complicated to prove that assertion, try simplifying your code or maybe using `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers.